# Is there a way to copy all objects inside a S3 bucket to Redshift using a Wildcard?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-redshift

I have an `S3 Bucket` called `Facebook`

The structure is like this :

```
Facebook/AUS/transformedfiles/YYYYMMDDHH/payments.csv
Facebook/IND/transformedfiles/YYYYMMDDHH/payments.csv
Facebook/SEA/transformedfiles/YYYYMMDDHH/payments.csv
```

Is there a way to copy all `payments.csv` to `AWS Redshift`?
something like :

```
copy payments Facebook/*/transformedfiles/YYYYMMDDHH/payments.csv
```

Answer (score 1):

No, because the `FROM` clause accepts an object prefix, and implies a trailing wildcard.

If you want to load specific files, you'll need to [use a manifest](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/loading-data-files-using-manifest.html) file. You would build this manifest by calling `ListObjects` and programmatically selecting the files you want.

A manifest file is also necessary if you're creating the files and immediately uploading them, because S3 is eventually consistent -- if you rely on it selecting files with a prefix, it might miss some.